# how to manage list functions using futon?

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

Is there a way I can make the futon display results of list-functions and help me edit them the way it does with map/reduce functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet, there is an [issue ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-417) about this, but still unresolved as of now.

Although not entirely related, there is an [effort to include Bespin](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-792) as part of Futon, and I'm hoping the ability to work with `_show` and `_list` functions is in tow.

Comment: I wonder what's the update on this.  It's been almost 2 years.  Is there a way to contribute to the CouchDB project by donating some money?